# What is this compilation error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When attempting to compile, I'm getting the following error:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes
>   Symbol ""public: void __thiscall Area::createArea(void)"
>   (?createArea@Area@@QAEXXZ)" in Funktion "_main". 1>D:\C++
>   Projekte\EREBOS_2\Debug\EREBOS_2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht
>   aufgelöste externe Verweise.

English translation:

> 1> main.obj: error LNK2019: unresolved external reference to Symbol ""
>   public: void __thiscall Area :: create area (void) " (? create area
>   Area @@@QAEXXZ) "function in" _main "1> D:. \ C ++ Projects \ EREBOS_2
>   \ Debug \ EREBOS_2.exe: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "MainPlayer.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int y;
int x;

using namespace std;

void createArea()
{
    int area[15][15];

    for(int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 15; y++)
        {
            area[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++)
    {
        area[1][y] = 1;
        area[15][y] = 1;
    }
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int y = 0; y <15; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
        {
            cout << area[x][y];
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void MainMenu:: createMenu()
{
    int typed;
    system("cls");
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "   --------------" << endl;
    cout << "   | 1) Start   |" << endl;
    cout << "   | 2) Hilfe   |" << endl;
    cout << "   | 3) Credits |" << endl;
    cout << "   | 4) Beenden |" << endl;
    cout << "   --------------" << endl;
    cin >> typed;
    if(typed == 1)
    {
        cout << "...still a whole lot of work to do..." << endl;
    }
}
```

---

```
#include <string>
class MainMenu
{
public:
    void createMenu();
};
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "MainPlayer.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Mainplayer:: showData()
{
    using namespace std;
    int health = 100;
    int xp = 0;
    int lvl = 1;
    int gold = 10;
    std:: string Name = "Namenloser";
    system("cls");
    cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << Name << endl;
    cout << "Leben: " << health << "/100" << endl;
    cout << "Erfahrung: " << xp << "/" << lvl*10 << endl;
    cout << "Level: " << lvl << "/50" << endl;
    cout << "Gold: " << gold << endl;
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;
}
```

---

```
#include <string>
class Mainplayer
{
    public:
        int health;
        int xp;
        int lvl;
        int gold;
        std:: string Name;
        void showData();
        int playercoordy;
        int playercoordx;
};
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "MainPlayer.h"
#include "Area.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void maingame();

int main()
{
    system("title EREBOS 2");
    Mainplayer MainChar; 
    MainMenu menu;
    Area MainArea; 
    menu.createMenu();
    MainChar.showData();
    MainArea.createArea();
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the {, } and };.....my foul....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your code to space the different code files better; adding new lines can clear this up. Also, please try and have the important errors in English; I've gone and translated it using Google Translate; feel free to edit if it didn't translate properly.

Comment: Those are linker errors, not compiler errors. C++ is first compiled, then linked. Resolving linker errors is generally a different process than resolving compiler errors.

Comment: Do you also have an answer or just this comment ? :D

Comment: And thanks for the english translation :)

Answer (score 2):

The message means you try to call "public: void __thiscall Area::createArea(void)" but then the linker doesn't find that function.

The closest thing I see is MainArea.createArea(); - I'm guessing that either you haven't implemented the function (in Area.cpp, which you didn't show us), or you simply aren't linking Area.o, or not in the needed sequence.

See [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)